# Error al exportar un JSON a CSV

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, csv

Tengo un problema con mi código cuando trato de exportar un json a csv pero este aparece así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es todo mi codigo

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(document).on('click', '#exportar-alumnos', function(){

    var jsonval;

    $.getJSON("http://localhost/api_biblioteca/AlumTable/read.php", function(data){
      jsonval=data;
      console.log(jsonval);
      if (jsonval == null) {
        return ;
      }
      JSONToCSVConvertor(jsonval, "Concentrado", true);
    });
  });
});


function JSONToCSVConvertor(JSONData, ReportTitle, ShowLabel) {
  //If JSONData is not an object then JSON.parse will parse the JSON string in an Object
  var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;

  console.log(arrData);

  var CSV = '';
  //Set Report title in first row or line

  CSV += ReportTitle + '\r\n\n';

  //This condition will generate the Label/Header
  if (ShowLabel) {
    var row = "";

    //This loop will extract the label from 1st index of on array
    for (var index in arrData[0]) {

      //Now convert each value to string and comma-seprated
      row += index + ',';
    }

    row = row.slice(0, -1);

    //append Label row with line break
    CSV += row + '\r\n';
  }

  console.log(CSV);

  //1st loop is to extract each row
  for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
    var row = "";

    //2nd loop will extract each column and convert it in string comma-seprated
    for (var index in arrData[i]) {
      row += '"' + arrData[i][index] + '",';
    }

    row.slice(0, row.length - 1);

    //add a line break after each row
    CSV += row + '\r\n';
  }

  if (CSV == '') {
    alert("Invalid data");
    return;
  }

  //Generate a file name
  var fileName = "Biblioteca_";
  //this will remove the blank-spaces from the title and replace it with an underscore
  fileName += ReportTitle.replace(/ /g, "_");

  //Initialize file format you want csv or xls
  var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);

  // Now the little tricky part.
  // you can use either>> window.open(uri);
  // but this will not work in some browsers
  // or you will not get the correct file extension    

  //this trick will generate a temp <a /> tag
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = uri;

  //set the visibility hidden so it will not effect on your web-layout
  link.style = "visibility:hidden";
  link.download = fileName + ".csv";

  //this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

**El error lo detecte en esta parte del código**

```
 //This condition will generate the Label/Header
  if (ShowLabel) {
    var row = "";

    //This loop will extract the label from 1st index of on array
    for (var index in arrData[0]) {

      //Now convert each value to string and comma-seprated
      row += index + ',';
    }

    row = row.slice(0, -1);

    //append Label row with line break
    CSV += row + '\r\n';
  }
```

*Llevo un rato tratando de corregir el problema, pero la verdad no se cual es el problema, no se el error proviene del IF o  por el For o quizás ambos. Y la verdad de un rato de estar probando soluciones ninguna funciona por lo que prefiero preguntar antes de continuar.*

Como datos adicionales aquí esta un ejemplo de la estructura de mi json:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es la estructura ya en un array que obtuve con un console.log:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues, me está funcionando, podrías compartir el JSON para ver si es que ahí es el error ? .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás tratando de iterar directamente sobre `arrData`, pero debería ser `arrData.records`, que es donde se almacenan los registros que quieres agregar al CSV.

Modificaciones:

- En el ciclo para valores estoy usando [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach), es más sencillo que un *for* numérico
- La [función flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions) es solo para "simplificar" un poco el código
- En lugar de concatenar, uso [plantillas de texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) que, definitivamente, ayuda a tener un código más legible

```js
let jsondata = { "records": [
  {
    "enter": "2020-08-10 12:00:37",
    "Enrolmed": "180610",
    "name": "Fabricio Guzmán Vite",
    "rank": "5",
    "group": "B",
    "EducationProgram": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "enter": "2020-08-10 12:00:37",
    "Enrolmed": "180610",
    "name": "Fabricio Guzmán Vite",
    "rank": "5",
    "group": "B",
    "EducationProgram": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "enter": "2020-08-10 12:00:37",
    "Enrolmed": "180610",
    "name": "Fabricio Guzmán Vite",
    "rank": "5",
    "group": "B",
    "EducationProgram": "N/A"
  }
]};

function JSONToCSVConvertor(JSONData, ReportTitle, ShowLabel) {
  //If JSONData is not an object then JSON.parse will parse the JSON string in an Object
  var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;

  var CSV = '';
  //Set Report title in first row or line

  CSV += ReportTitle + '\r\n\r\n';

  //This condition will generate the Label/Header
  if (ShowLabel) {
    var row = "";

    //This loop will extract the label from 1st index of on array
    for (var index in arrData.records[0]) {
      //Now convert each value to string and comma-seprated
      row += index + ',';
    }

    //append Label row with line break
    CSV += row.slice(0, -1) + '\r\n';
  }
  // Recorrer todos los registros
  arrData.records.forEach(record => {
    let row = '';
    // Recorrer columnas
    for(var index in record) {
      // Obtener valor de cada columna y encerrar entre comillas
      row += `"${record[index]}",`;
    }
    CSV += row.slice(0, -1) + '\r\n';
  });
  console.log(CSV);
}
JSONToCSVConvertor(jsondata, 'Concentrado', true)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ya estaba algo frustrado por no saber en lo que estaba mal. En verdad te lo agradezco me salvaste.